# URL Format of a nested structure with 3 or more layers

Tags: url, structure, format, nested-set

I have a nested Structure with 3 layers like so:

- Home
- Services

  - Service A

    - Sub Service A
    - Sub Service B
  - Service B
- About Us
- Contact

Now I would like the nesting to be reflected in the URL like so:

`http://example.com/services/service-a/sub-service-a`

I used `{parent.slug}/{slug}` as the URL Format and this is working for two but not three layers.

How would the correct format look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the Nested Entries URL format to:

```
{parent.uri}/{slug}
```

Comment: As a side question: I lost this piece of code in the field while setting the structure to one level, then I could find it nowhere in the documentation of craft or twig. There is no ordered overview of this kind of variables?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, could you please expand on it a bit?

Comment: To put it simple: where can I find this {parent.uri} in the docs?

Comment: I don't see it in the docs, but the field itself contains instructions saying that "you can include tags that output entry properties", and parent is documented here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#parent

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's give me an idea about how the docs are setup :-)

Comment: Now with the new `headlessMode` in Craft 3.3 the entries url format is gone. How would I defined the URI now?

Comment: Probably better to post this as a new question :)